# CakePHP 2.1 Weird answer format for find command when using DBMS functions

Tags: cakephp, find, cakephp-2.1

I have the following search query (need to have the year/month and slug of a post in order for a proper redirect after a comment was added).

```
$settingsForPostQuery = array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Post.slug',
                'YEAR(Post.date_published) as year',
                'MONTH(Post.date_published) as month'
            ),
            'conditions' => array('Post.id' => $this -> request -> params['post_id'])
        );
// unbind post model to fetch only necessary stuff
$this -> Comment -> Post -> unbindModel(array(
            'hasMany' => array('Comment'),
            'hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('Tag'),
            'belongsTo' => array('Category')
));

$post = $this -> Comment -> Post -> find('published', $settingsForPostQuery);
```

Thats what I get with `Debugger::dump($post);`:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Post' => array(
        'slug' => 'this-is-a-second-test-post-in-the-category-internet'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'year' => '2012',
        'month' => '6'
    )
)
)
```

Wouldn't something be more logical:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Post' => array(
        'slug' => 'this-is-a-second-test-post-in-the-category-internet',
        'year' => '2012',
        'month' => '6'
     )      
  )
)
```

In case you need the info, 'published' is a custom find type, defined as follows:

```
protected function _findPublished($state, $query, $results = array()) {
    if ($state === 'before') {
        $query['conditions']['Post.is_archived'] = false;
        $query['conditions'][] = 'Post.date_published <= now()';
        return $query;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

**EDIT**

I found out that when using only Post.date_published instead of YEAR(Post.date_published), Post.date_published also appears in the Post array, just as slug does. Why does using MYSQL functions alter this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what happens in CakePHP when you add fields in the query, I believe you can make them be part of the main data array with the correct alias naming convention of `MyModel__MyField`:

```
$settingsForPostQuery = array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Post.slug',
            'YEAR(Post.date_published) as Post__year',
            'MONTH(Post.date_published) as Post__month'
        ),
        'conditions' => array('Post.id' => $this -> request -> params['post_id'])
    );
```

[Read more here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html).
By the way, you should look into [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) for limit the models queried instead of unbinding them :)

Comment: Thanks man. Adding virtual fields for year and month (on the fly) and using Post__year/Post__month as suggested works perfectly. Also, thank you for the hint for Containable, will look into that.